# Fragment containing two ListFragments

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to set up a tablet-friendly interface. Therefore I have two Navigation Tabs, that open two Fragments. 
Main Activity's onCreate:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab mainTab = mActionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Articoli")
            .setTabListener(new TabEventListener(new InListFragment(0)));
    Tab favTab = mActionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Preferiti")
            .setTabListener(new TabEventListener(new TestFragment("Preferiti")));

    mActionBar.addTab(mainTab);
    mActionBar.addTab(favTab);

}
```

And this is my TabEvengListener:

```
public class TabEventListener implements TabListener {
Fragment mFragment;

public TabEventListener(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragment = fragment;
}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mFragment.getTag());
}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(mFragment);
}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    //NOTHING ATM
}
```

}

Now, I'm referring to this API Demo: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.html where I have an Activity with a layout containing one or two fragments, depending on screen state. Here comes my problem: I've not an activity, but a fragment, and I can't find any way to declare a layout in order to get the two sub-fragments.
I'd like to have - on Tablets - an interface with two panes, one with a "Titles List" (the conversation list) and another one with the "detail list" (the texts).

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do what I explained, or I must remove the Navigation Tabs so I can use an Activity instead of a Fragment and follow the API demo.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) you'll find this definition

"A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity" and "A fragment must always be embedded in an activity"

So in my opinion the answer is "No, you cannot"

Comment: Is it possible to use Activities instead of Fragments for the Navigation Tabs?

Comment: Yes with deprecated TabHost and TabWidget and I don't really like this solution.